# Solving a second-order differential equation with both Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: symbolic-math, differential-equations, maxima, wxmaxima

I want to solve the Fourier’s law for the heat equation

of an isolated electrically heated rod:

with a Dirichlet boundary condition of

and a Neumann boundary condition of

where

- x is the length coordinate
- L is the length of the rod
- K is the thermal conductivity of the material (assumed constant)
- Q is the internal heat generation per unit length
- q heat load from the left side
- T<sub>L</sub> is the ambient temperature on the right side

To solve the differential equation I used the

```
eqn : 'diff(T, x, 2) + Q / k = 0;
sol : ode2(eqn, T, x);
```

giving the correct general form of

however when applying the boundary conditions using:

```
bc2(sol, x=0, 'diff(T, x)=-q/k, x=L, T=TL);
```

I get the wrong answer of

while what I expected to see was

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, because the Neumann boundary condition happened in the `x = 0` I could use the

```
ic2(sol, x=L, T=TL, 'diff(T, x)=-q/k);
```

to get the correct result: